# What are these fixings for a printer's (letterpress) tray, and how can I make them?

Tags: cabinetry, restoration

I'm starting on a woodworking project to build a spice rack that looks like an old typesetter's or printer's tray. I've got most of the design worked out, but I cannot figure out how to make these fixings (or even what they're called). I could make it work without them, but they look very neat, and I like my fakery to be as accurate as possible.

[image: fixings on printer's tray]

They seem to be a thin metal disk, that is bent four ways, or on some of the joins, in a T shape, with what looks like a pin hammered through the middle. I'd love to know:

a) what are these fixing called? I might be able to just buy them, but despite extensive googling, I still have no idea what they're called.

b) any suggestions for making them. I've been thinking of some sort of jig that I can hammer some thin brass disks into, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Long shot, but try submitting to Google Lens.

Comment: Believe it or not, this question is a duplicate. [Are these brass “cross caps” (used on type cases) still made?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/6753/492)

Comment: If you could source, or make, thin brass disks of the right type (or you can easily anneal it) then there's no reason you couldn't produce these in number with a little effort an ingenuity. I'd make a two-part press mould of sorts (from wood) and just press out the basic shape as a repeat operation, then perhaps form the central depression as a separate operation.

Comment: I am so surprised this is already a duplicate!

Comment: @Graphus Thanks for the advice! I'll see if I can get some brass disks, and have a go.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate because the OP is asking how to make them, which is an element that is not in the other question.

Comment: How many were you looking for by the way? And will you have a repeat need for them or is this just for a one-off?

Comment: @Graphus probably 50? I think something like a jewellers disk punch would work to punch the disks, then a wooden former, like you suggest. I actually thought I could get away with just making the bottom former, and use a piece of metal rod to shape into the former. Don't quite know how it will work yet, but I have an idea now. It's going to be a one off for now, unless family and friends want one :p